# Creating a map of boundary regions with Postgresql Lat/Long data

Tags: postgresql, maps, gis, geospatial, boundary

I have a Postgres database of U.S. zipcodes and their lat/long data.

My requirement is to divide these zipcodes into non overlapping regions.

All regions have some center zipcode. All regions grow outward, starting from it's center until they intersect with another region.

I do not know the radius/size of each region. All I know is the list of zipcodes that can be considered as centers of the regions.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a voronoi diagram. It's the dual of the delaunay triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download zip code tabulation area shape files.  See https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html